# Transferring files to IIS (attempted using PHPStorm & Finder)

Tags: iis, phpstorm, web-deployment, bower, finder

I have a working local copy of a simple website I would like to deploy to an IIS (Internet Information Server) running on my local network. Running on my computer on MAMP, everything works perfectly. However, after I try to upload all the files to the web server and load the index.html it fails to `GET` many different files necessary to load the page. Here is an example error line in the console:

`GET http://WEBSITE.com/scripts/bootstrap-wizard-custom.js 403 (Forbidden)`

Here the methods I have tried to upload files to the live server:

1. Using `CMD+K` in Finder, connecting to the live server with an address like `smb://webserver`, and then simply dragging files from my local folder to the `wwwroot` folder.
2. Using PHPStorm (on Windows), selecting the mapped network folder as my workspace, and then "Deploying" all the files to the server by clicking an "Upload to [webserver]" button.

What is the best way to go about transferring these files from my local machine to a web server on the same network?

Comment: FTP? (IIS 7.5+ has FTP support bundled; for 7.0 it needs to be installed separately). So far it looks like file permission issue or IIS misconfiguration (i.e. the user account rights that site is running under). You better speak to the Windows admin about better diagnosing the issue -- right now I do not see how PhpStorm can be a fault link here)

Comment: I was thinking of trying FTP, but I figured that's only worth it when I'm connecting to a remote server, like Amazon EC2. It turns out it was a permissions problem though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a permissions problem. After some permission changing, it now works. Fixed!